# How to loop through lists and compare sums between two numbers and finally returns the answer with the closest index grouping?

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, slice, closest

Basically I'm trying to find 2 elements in a list that adds together to the correct given sum.

Example:

```
aList = [1,5,6,3,8,9,4]  sum = 10
```

now with the above conditions I will expect 2 results:

```
[1, 9] and [6, 4]
```

The answer should be [6, 4] because they are closest to each other. 1 to 9 need to take 4 steps while [6, 4] only need to take 3. Shortest index differences.

My code is below and it doesn't work for the above example:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
for i in ints:
    for b in ints[i:]:
        if i + b == s:
            return [i,b]
else:
    return None
```

So how would you check between closest index with out writing another loop?

Comment: Did you get any error message?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the problem is not that the code "doesn't work" in the sense that it fails at executing ; the problem is that it returns the first "working" pair, not that which is closest...

Comment: @Archeo yes you are correct it works but doesn't return the closest index pair. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find numbers with least ammount of steps, loop over the distance and try all tuples with the given distance in between - you should not try pairs with 4 spaces in between when you did not exhaust all tuples with distance 3...

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    for distance in range(1, len(ints)):
        for idx in range(len(ints) - distance):
            if ints[idx] + ints[idx + distance] == s:
                return [ints[idx], ints[idx + distance]]
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

A "simple" (not most efficient - see another posted answer : adding up a loop to procede by looking at spaces between characters is better) solution :

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    answer = None
    distance = 10
    for i in ints:
        for b in ints[i:]:
            if i + b == s and abs(i - b) < distance:
                answer = (i, b)
                distance = abs(i - b)
return answer
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store all possible solutions to the list before returning anything.

```
a = []
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    for i in ints:
        for b in ints[i:]:
            if i + b == s:
                a.append([i,b])
    return a

aList = [1,5,6,3,8,9,4]

print sum_pairs(aList,10)
```

Output: `[[1, 9], [6, 4]]`

Answer (score 0):

You weren't really testing at all for the differences between the pairs that you have, simply returning the list of all matches found for the sum you entered.

```
nums = [1,5,6,3,8,9,4]

def sum_pairs(ints, s):
  matches = []
  for i in range(len(ints)):
    x = ints[i]
    for y in ints[i + 1:]:
      if x + y == s: matches.append([x, y])
  differences = {}
  for x, y in matches:
    differences[abs(x - y)] = [x, y]
  return differences[min(differences.keys())]

>>> sum_pairs(nums, 10)
# [6, 4]
```